# MVVM WPF обращение к объекту из другого окна

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В очередной раз столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть модель

```
namespace WPF.Model
{
   class PriceList
{
  public  List<Material> Materials { get; set; }


    public PriceList()
    {
        Materials = new List<Material>();
    }
}
}
```

Есть к ней некая VM

```
 namespace WinDoorsWPF.ViewModel
{
 class Price : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    PriceList pList = new PriceList();

   public PriceList PList
    {
        get { return pList; }
        set { pList = value; OnPropertyChanged("pList"); }
    }


    public Price()
    {

    }

    public void GetPricesGoogle()
    {


    }
```

В MainWindow

```
Price price = new Price();
price.GetPricesGoogle();
```

После нажатия на кнопку, во втором окне должен отобразится уже инициализированный Price. 
Но в нем создается новый объект. И соответственно то, что нужно не отображается.

XAML второго окна:

```
 <Window x:Class="WinDoorsWPF.View.PriceListWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinDoorsWPF.View"
    xmlns:viewModel = "clr-namespace:WinDoorsWPF.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PriceListWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
 <Grid>
     <DataGrid  Name="priceListGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding PList.Materials}"  
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="215" Margin="160,105,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="568">

     </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

А дальше

```
        public PriceListWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Price() ;
    }
```

Есть конечно идея создать *static* поле в VM и обращаться к нему напрямую, но что-то мне подсказывает, что так делать не надо.

На данный момент в моем понимании, что я где-то упустил понимание MVVM, что по сути весь код должен выполнятся в VM. Но я не понимаю, каким образом создать объект, чтобы можно было как в winform передавать его. Ну или обращаться к нему.

Понимаю, что во View должен быть по сути только код Xaml.

Comment: Таким образом конечно работает, но если необходимо будет передать два объекта, тогда что? 
private void priceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PriceListWindow f = new PriceListWindow();
            f.DataContext = price;
            f.Show();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно задействовать паттерн [издатель-подписчик](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

На [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866547/Publisher-Subscriber-pattern-with-Event-Delegate-a) есть хороший пример реализации.

Суть в том, что вы создаёте независимого посредника между вашими VM. Он предоставляет интерфейс, с помощью которого VM могут посылать друг другу сообщения с любой полезной нагрузкой.